# Expansion of sunlight

Tags: waves, shadow

I have very little background in physics so any help would be appreciated:
Assuming the sun is directly overhead (like at the equater during an Equinox), and I attempt to cast a shadow on the ground by holding a piece of paper five feet up parrallel to the ground. There is a one inch round hole in the center of the paper, making a hole in the shadow on the ground. My question is would this hole in the shadow be exactly one inch on the ground, or would it be larger due to the light expanding?

Comment: The Sun is not a point source, so the shadow would not have sharp edges. The area in the center fully open to the sunlight would be substantially smaller than one inch. The circle of the full ahadow would be substantially larger than one inch. The area in between would be filled with a partial shadow gradually changing density. Just draw it all on a piece of paper and you'll see. The actual "expansion" of light would be unmesuarably small  (about 20 parts in a trillion).

Comment: @safesphere. That's an answer if ever I saw one, and if you want an extra (short :) paragraph to cover the effects of reducing the hole size, I'll even throw in an Airy disc diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk

Comment: @countto10 I'm a big fan of apodization to remove Airy disks :) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodization

Comment: In addition and in  principle there would be diffraction at the edge even with a point source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the hole in the shadow would have a larger size than the original one.